# Add images to array, pick one at random and delete from array

Tags: c#, arrays, random

So I just started programming in C# (I do know the basics though). With friends I sometimes play a card game where you have to pick a card and according to what's on it, we have to do a challenge and the loser has to take a drink. Just for fun, I want to make this game as a Windows Form Application. I'm having issues with the images though. I want to get them from a folder that's in the directory of the program executable and add them to an array. Then I want to randomly select one (with the Random class) when a button is clicked. Once a card has been picked, I want it to be deleted from the array so it can't be chosen again.

I've been looking through quite a bit of tutorials on SO and other places, but I can't find something that fully works. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320293/shuffle-random-picture-from-resources-on-button-click) came closest, as it did select a random picture when a button was clicked and displayed it, but I didn't find a way to remove that picture from the array. How can I add the functionality to delete the image from the array?

Edit: I should've added that I've already tried some stuff that didn't work. I deleted that code though ('cause it didn't work), but I'll try some stuff again and post back when I can't make it work.

Comment: dont use an array - use a Stack or List.  After the image is used, remove it

Comment: **`but I can't find something that fully works`** Because there will never be a ready to go code that does what you want exactly as you have envisioned it. That's simple not how StackOverflow works. If you have the basics then why don't you try something, then if you're not able to get something specific portion of that code to work post here what you have tried, what should happen but isn't and your difficult with it so we can help you, but do not expect ready to go code here ever.

Comment: I know how SO works, and I should've added that I've tried adding some code by myself but it didn't work. I removed the code though, so I'll try something again and see if I can get it to work. If not, I'll add it to my original post.

@Plutonix care to explain why I shouldn't use arrays? Rather new to programming in C# so don't really know why I shouldn't use it.

Comment: @Alex are you familiar with `Index || SelectedIndex` ? also with out seeing what you have tried is really kind of hard for someone to lend you and direction outside of using a `List etc...` [C# Basics Tutorial - Collections](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_collections.htm)

Comment: arrays are 1990s tech.  if you remove an image from an array it leaves `null` at that element/index.  using a collection removes the element or slot as well as the image.  for purposes of not leaving resources undisposed, you ought to perhaps store the file name and create (and dispose) of one image at a time

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: An array is just fine, if you know ahead of time how many elements you will be dealing with. As far as how to do this, the general answer is to read the images into an array, and then [shuffle the array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). If you want help from StackOverflow, be sure to explain precisely what you've done so far, what it did, and how that was different from what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

According to the link in your example i will assume that in your code you represent an image as string.

Just use a list `List<string> images = new List<string>();` to hold your images

to add elements in the list use `images.Add(elemenet)` where `element` is of type `string`

to draw a randrom card use

```
Randrom randomNumber = new Random();
int extractedCard = randomNumber.Next(images.Length);
```

then display `images[extractedCard]`

and then you can easily remove that card from the list `images.RemoveAt(extractedCard)`